# Нужна ли запятая перед тире в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед тире? В Византии уже в VIII в. из испечённого для Евхаристии хлеба использовали обычно только особую, изъятую копием часть (,) - агнец.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**В Византии уже в VIII в. из испечённого для Евхаристии хлеба использовали обычно только особую, изъятую копием, часть – агнец.**

Сравнить: ...использовали обычно только особую часть - агнец.

Вопрос связан с обособлением оборота с пояснительным значением, Розенталь рекомендует такие обороты обособлять: "Случай пояснения находим также в предложениях типа: Астрономы наблюдали вспышки особых, **так называемых новых**, звезд. Ср. без уточнения: Астрономы наблюдали вспышки так называемых новых звезд (слова так называемых запятыми не выделяются)".

**Вот классические примеры с обособлением**: Каждое явление имеет свои, присущие только ему, признаки. Дашу удивила доморощенность всего этого, так нашумевшего, дерзновения. Чичиков немного озадачился таким, отчасти резким, определением.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего нужна, но не перед тире, а после "копием". Здесь "изъятую копием" - уточняющее приложение, без запятой получится как однородные определения, но с "особую" это просто невозможно по смыслу.

***...использовали обычно только особую, изъятую копием, часть - агнец.***
Или уж обе запятые убрать.

А лучше всего от греха подальше сформулировать так.

***...использовали обычно только изъятую копием особую часть - агнец.***

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна. Нет причин для обособления. Сравните:

*...использовали особую часть, изъятую копием, – агнец.*